# Electrical Potential Energy And forces Experienced By Particles

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics

I am really stuck on a question and would appreciate a helping hand.

A particle has a charge of $+3.5$ $\mu$$C$ and moves from point $A$ to point $B$, a distance of $0.5m$. The particle experiences a constant electric force and it's motion is along the line of action of the force. The difference between the particles electrical potential energy at point $A$ and point $B$ is $EPE_{A}$ $-$ $EPE_{B}$ $= +7.0x10^{-3} J$.

(a) Find the magnitude and direction and direction of the electric force that acts on the particle.

(b) Find the magnitude and direction of the electric field the particle experiences.

The fact that the work done is a positive quantity, leads me to think that the electric force acts in the direction from $A$ to $B$ but I don't know how to quantify it.

Thank you for any help you can give!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Relation between electric field and potential energy is given by

> V = E.dr                -----> (1)

where,

```
  V - Potential Difference

  E - Electric field

  dr- small distance between the two points at which potential difference is calculated
```

Also, we know that the electric force is given by -

> F = qE                  ------> (2)

where,

```
  F - Electric force
  q - it is the net charge on which the force is acting
```

For answering the first part of your question -
(i)   From equation (1) and (2), we have -

> F = q * V / dr

Now just put the values according to your question which are -

q = +3.5 μC

dr = 0.5 m

V = 7.0 X $10^{-3}$

Then the you will get force (F) = 4.9 X $10^{-2}$ N

(ii) Using the (2) equation you can find the Electric field. (Calculate it yourself!)

Now while you find the direction of Electric field you must note one thing that the electric field for the axial charge distribution is simply from positive to negative and since in your case the electric field is uniform you can simply conclude that it would be from A to B (also the work done is positive).

To quantify Work Done-

> **Work Done = Force * Displacement**

```
    Work Done = qE.dr = qV             ------>(3)
```

So, from (3) you can get that work done is positive and in the same direction as of potential energy (since here position vectors of V do not change).